# Page hangs after commandbutton action inside datatable

Tags: jsf, icefaces, icefaces-3

i'm working on a project using icefaces api, i run into a probleme i used a commandButton inside a dataTable that delets the object in the row but when i click on it server hangs and keeps loading without showing any errors in console.

using apache-tomcat-7.0.75

my html code :

```html
 <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
         <ui:param name="titre" value="Liste de Comptes"/>
         <ui:define name="content">
         <f:view>
            <h:form id="form">
   <ace:dataTable id="cptTable" value="#{compte.allComptes}"
    var="cpt" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10">
    
    ...
    
    <ace:column width="10">
                <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Opérations"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:commandLink id="dlt" actionListener="#{compte.deletCompte}"  title="Supprimer" >
                   <f:param name="idcpt" value="#{cpt.id_compte}"/>
                   <ace:ajax execute="dlt" render="form"/>
                  <br/>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:link outcome="modifierCompte" value="Modifier le compte" >
                  <f:param name="id" value="#{cpt.id_compte}"/>
                </h:link>
                <ice:outputText value=" | "/>
                 <h:link outcome="operation" value="Operation sur le compte" >
                  <f:param name="id" value="#{cpt.id_compte}"/>
                </h:link>
                 
              </ace:column>
   </ace:dataTable>
  </h:form>
  </f:view>
  </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

my bean :

```js
package jee.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import jee.dao.dao;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Compte implements Serializable{

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -7177239517089845251L;
 
 private int id_compte;
 private int id_agence;
 private int id_client;
 private String num_compte;
 private double solde;
 private String date_creation_compte;
 public ArrayList<Compte> comptes;
 
 public Compte() {
  super();
  this.id_agence=1;
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public Compte(int id_compte, int id_agence, int id_client,
   String num_compte, double solde, String date_creation_compte,
   ArrayList<Compte> comptes) {
  super();
  this.id_compte = id_compte;
  this.id_agence = id_agence;
  this.id_client = id_client;
  this.num_compte = num_compte;
  this.solde = solde;
  this.date_creation_compte = date_creation_compte;
 }
 
 

 public int getId_compte() {
  return id_compte;
 }

 public void setId_compte(int id_compte) {
  this.id_compte = id_compte;
 }

 public int getId_agence() {
  return id_agence;
 }

 public void setId_agence(int id_agence) {
  this.id_agence = id_agence;
 }

 public int getId_client() {
  return id_client;
 }

 public void setId_client(int id_client) {
  this.id_client = id_client;
 }

 public String getNum_compte() {
  return num_compte;
 }

 public void setNum_compte(String num_compte) {
  this.num_compte = num_compte;
 }

 public double getSolde() {
  return solde;
 }

 public void setSolde(double solde) {
  this.solde = solde;
 }

 public String getDate_creation_compte() {
  return date_creation_compte;
 }

 public void setDate_creation_compte(String date_creation_compte) {
  this.date_creation_compte = date_creation_compte;
 }

 
 public void setComptes(ArrayList<Compte> comptes) {
  this.comptes = comptes;
 }

 public ArrayList<Compte> getComptes() {
  dao d = new dao();
  ExternalContext ec =
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
  comptes=d.getComptes((String)session.getAttribute("login"));

  return comptes;
 }
   
 public void deletCompte(){
  dao d = new dao();
  ExternalContext ec =
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  Map<String,String> params = ec.getRequestParameterMap();
  
  d.supprimerCompte(Integer.parseInt(params.get("idcpt")));
 }
 
 
 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:link outcome="modifierCompte" value="Modifier le compte" >
              <f:param name="id" value="#{cpt.id_compte}"/>
            </h:link>
            <ice:outputText value=" | "/>
             <h:link outcome="operation" value="Operation sur le compte" >
              <f:param name="id" value="#{cpt.id_compte}"/>
            </h:link>
```

Duplicate id's can  cause that. You have duplicate names here f:param name="id"  when rendered does it create a duplicate id use debug to verify tou have no duplicate id's.  Each row should have a unique id I usually add the row number to the id

Comment: thank you for your answer, i did what u said and changed the id's but unfortunatly i still have the same probleme